# Where has BuildStep gone?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm reusing 2010 tfs build scripts in TFSBuild 2013. 
I've had to remove my BuildSteps because the task is no longer valid!

What is the recommended alternative to logging progress to the TFSBuild 2013 "Activity Log" ?

Comment: The post/pre-build scripts wouldn't do the work for you?

Comment: I hadnt planned on getting into the build templates at all, I was led to believe my existing build scripts would work just fine, I'm learning that it's not so simple, never is. The BuildStep is gone by default then?

Comment: I see that the BuildStep class is still present and public in the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.ProcessComponents.dll file (Version=12.0.0.0).

Comment: I see it is. And if I include it in my proj file with <UsingTask TaskName="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.BuildStep" AssemblyFile="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.ProcessComponents.dll" />
   should it work as before, writing to the Activity Log?

Comment: Doesnt look like it works using the UsingTask above! Build2013Test\src\TeamBuildTypes\ReleaseVS2013\Help.targets (14): The "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.BuildStep" task could not be loaded from the assembly \PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.ProcessComponents.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.ProcessComponents.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct

Comment: Half a hack found here but it only allows the BuildStep to be found it still doesnt show the message. Pass a Parameter to the build "TeamBuildRefPath" http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/05/05/executing-legacy-msbuild-scripts-in-tfs-2010-build.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the hack mentioned does work. I can now see my old BuildSteps in the Activity log on 2013
Half a hack found here but it only allows the BuildStep to be found it still doesnt show the message. Pass a Parameter to the build "TeamBuildRefPath" http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/05/05/executing-legacy-msbuild-scripts-in-tfs-2010-build.aspx